# How to handle different csproj

Tags: version-control, project-management

I am working in a team of five. We are working on a C# application with five csprojects.

The problem is that for each csproject, each of my colleagues has their own ideas on how to reference a DLL; some would like to link in by Project reference, other would like to link in the DLL only. So each and every one of us will have our own csproject.

I want all of them to check in their csproject; but given that every copy of csproject is different, there isn't really a feasible mechanism to do that, is there? But if I don't ask them to check in their csproject, then every time they add a new file, I would have to manually edit my csproject and that's very tedious, not to mention that it beats the purpose of continuous integration.

Is there any strategy to handle this? **I know it would be best to enforce a standard, but is there any other option leaving this aside?**

There is a reason why the csproject content is different for everyone; not everyone has all of the five csprojects, and not everyone *can* have all of the 5 csprojects. So invariably some will have to end up having to reference DLLs instead of projects, and some *want* to reference by projects for the ease of debugging. If I were to enforce a standard, as the answers here suggest, I would have to solve this issue.

As to why we need to split into multiple csprojects, that's because we want to reuse some parts of the code for other applications, and because not everyone can have all access to the source code. It's more political than technological.

Comment: Why do you have 5 csprojects? Can't you just agree on a format and use 1 csproject?

Comment: are you talking about .csproj or .csproj.user files ? Everyone should have a .csproj.user file but that isnt useful in source control at all.

Comment: Andrew: He's talking about how the project references other projects/assemblies.  So that would be a .csproj rather than a .csproj.user thing.

Comment: @double-beep Well, it's definitely about programming (using tools commonly used by programmers is on-topic here), but it's also opinion-based.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is not how to handle it with Source Control.

Your problem is that you (or management) needs to get your team to adopt a set of standards the entire team follows.

If you let everyone follow their own mish-mash of ideas and do not get team cohesion on the basics it will only end in tears...

Comment: Why this is upvoted? Where an answer here? Why this is not comment?

Comment: Simply because prior to his edit (bold text) I provided a solution to this *problem*, even if it wasn't the *answer* he wanted. My stance still does not change despite his edit. IF he needs to maintain multiple .csproj files for 1 project under source control, his team's methods/procedures/setup are broken. They are what should be fixed, not perverting source control as it just leads down a dark path of bad practices...

Comment: Sorry. s/a solution to/advice for

Answer (score 7):

You're almost certainly solving the wrong problem.  If you fork the .csproj files to cater to invididual preferences, you are incurring additional work and introducing the likelihood of errors, for exactly the reason you describe -- every time Alice adds a file to AlicesX.csproj, Bob has to learn about this and add the same file to BobsX.csproj.

You really need to consider this as a problem of standards and team dynamics: agree on how DLLs will be referenced in the master sources, and require everyone to stick to that.  If the "losing" side don't like to work that way, sure, they can use their preferred style in their private working copies.  But you really only want one master source, and you want to work towards getting everybody to buy into the way the master source does it.

**Per your edit:** If you really, really cannot come to an agreement with your colleagues, then I would still suggest a single master, but write a little utility that the dissenters can use that converts project references to DLL references (or vice versa).  .csproj files are just XML so this is pretty trivial to do.  If you cannot even agree on what is going to be the repository format, then you will need to maintain parallel .csproj files, but I'd still write the utility to ensure that changes made to DllReferencingProj.csproj get copied to ProjectReferencingProj.csproj.  But I still say you're just making more work and storing up more pain for yourself than if you had the squabble and got it over with: in order to function as a team, you're going to need to find some way of resolving disputes, and this is as good as test case as any.

Answer (score 4):

Time to make everyone grow up and follow a standard.  If you're all working on the same code you should decide together whether referencing the dll or the project is best and then stick to it.  Once you guys figure this one out you can decide whether to indent 2 or 4 spaces or a tab.  Then decide whether to put your curly braces on the same line as or the next line after your function declarations.  I'm not even going to speak to the vagaries of Hungarian notation...

Comment: Ah...coding standards...everybody should have one. Even if only to constantly fight over its content. :)

Answer (score 0):

Our configuration is as follows:

- Project -> copy dll to common folder
- Project -> copy dll to common folder
- Main Project -> Copy exe to common folder, run application from common folder

Doesn't much matter how you reference using this configuration, the dlls will be picked up from the application folder and you're golden.

Answer (score -2):

Continuous integration shouldn't care about your .csproj files.  I guess they're MSBUILD files? Or something?

Don't use them for CI.  They're junk.  They accrue garbage because they make too many things invisible.  Create a clean build structure that is independent of them, you'll be thankful you did. And then only check in a project file when you're adding something, and everyone else can update/merge.  You don't need to have the same or even similar project files most of the time.  On my team we don't even run the same version of VS across all workstations.

Comment: This is terrible advice. Strive for everyone running the same version of everything as much as possible, otherwise you're needlessly introducing more paths that your developers need to go down in order to debug problems properly. And there's no reason he shouldn't check-in project files for use with CI. They define criteria under which the solution should be built. They're part of the solution, they should be treated as such.

Comment: -1. .csproj files work perfectly well for CI. They are XML files and are quite clear. I agree with The Matt - version standardization is critical.

Comment: No, it's not.  How do I know this?  Because our shop runs it differently, and we're much happier for it.  Microsoft has yet to create a project or solution format that works well with any non-MS technology.  It's probably great if you've got the entire TFS setup and a team that's in love with using all the same setup, but if you're using non-MS tools or a variety of configurations there are much better ways than relying on the junk-accumulating project file format.

Comment: @The Matt: The number of situations where multiple versions of Visual Studio introduces problems (assuming you're all at least agreed on a .NET framework version, of course) is close enough to zero for most application developers that it can be ignored completely.

Comment: I would applaud anyone that could maintain tight enough control over their dev group that everyone's "C:" drive is laid out in identical fashion to everyone else and no one ever tinkers. But that is not the real world especially using offshore developers. They all go cowboy/rogue all the time, whether intentional or not, and soon enough check in changes that break. I agree with Mike. Let's understand that SOURCE control means code, not configuration of machinery and mechanics. I guarantee that anyone thinking their environment is "standardized" is fooling themselves. Omit csproj from SC.